# HttpTestingController expectOne not working when actual request is nested within a promise

Tags: angular, jasmine

I am trying to unit test a service which gets a value from another service (returns a Promise) then execute http GET request.

I am using HttpTestingController from @angular/common/http/testing to mock the http request. Here is the test and prod code :

**tested.service.spec.ts**

```js
it('should get base url from indexedDb then execute http get request', (async () => {
  fakeParametresService.getBaseUrl.and.returnValue(Promise.resolve({valeur: 'http://host:port'}));

  testedService.get<any>('/endpoint').then((response: any) => {
    expect(response.key).toBe('value');
  });

  await http.expectOne('http://host:port/endpoint').flush({key: 'value'});
  http.verify();    
}));
```

**tested.service.ts**

```js
async get<T>(endpoint: string): Promise<T> {
  const baseUrl = await this.parametresService.getBaseUrl();
  return this.http.get<T>(`${baseUrl.valeur}${endpoint}`).toPromise();
}
```

It seems that a http request nested within a promise cannot be mocked that way. But maybe it's a misunderstanding from me.

Comment: I have similar problem with rxjs streams. `transmitted$.switchMapTo(this.initializePayment).switchMapTo(this.getPaymentUrl)`  . these methods are private and make http calls, stream is only public...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For me it worked, to use the `fakeAsync` testzone. There you have the `tick()` function which waits until all promises are resolved and continues your test afterwards. The Problem is that you can't make any XHR request in the `fakeAsync` Zone, but it worked fine for me with the `HttpClientTestingModule`.

```js
it('should get base url from indexedDb then execute http get request', fakeAsync(() => {
  fakeParametresService.getBaseUrl.and.returnValue(Promise.resolve({valeur: 'http://host:port'}));

  testedService.get<any>('/endpoint').then((response: any) => {
    expect(response.key).toBe('value');
  });
  // wait until all Promises are resolved
  tick();
  http.expectOne('http://host:port/endpoint').flush({key: 'value'});
  http.verify();    
}));
```

Comment: I was able to get some tests working using `waitForAsync` instead, but this seems to work more consistently.  The problem is if the function under test makes more than one HTTP request, sequentially -- like looking up a record, then making another lookup based on the first one.  In that case you can make the request, tick, expect/verify, tick, etc.